# Wherever there is one letter between <li></li> tags, insert a <h3></h3> tag for that letter

Tags: regex

Wherever there is one letter between `<li></li>` tags, I would like to insert a `<h3></h3>` tag for that letter. For example:
`<li>A</li>` should look like this: `<li><h3>A</h3></li>`

How to do this with RegEx?
https://regexr.com/4rlc2

Comment: You should post some of the code you're using this regex in. This will give us context as well as a language to answer with. Plus, different languages have different "flavors" of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in your regex: `<li>(.)</li>`. You will then have access to what's between the parenthesis in your match (depending on which language you use it might look different, but this functionality is implemented pretty much everywhere). You can then replace with: `<li><h3>$1</h3></li>`.

Here's an example using JS:

```
a = '<li>A</li>'
r = /<li>(.)<\/li>/
a.match(r) // [ '<li>A</li>', 'A', index: 0, input: '<li>A</li>', groups: undefined ]
a.replace(r, '<li><h3>$1</h3></li>') // '<li><h3>A</h3></li>'
```